# Simpy: Store put/get with matching times

Tags: python, simpy

I want to simulate a taxi-passenger system. There are C taxi stands where taxis and passengers can match there before leaving. Since there are queues of both taxis and passengers, I am thinking of using Store with capacity = C, where passengers yield "get" requests, and taxis yield "put" requests.

However, the "get" request seems to take the resource (taxi) immediately from the store. How can I deal with matching times in this situation?

For example, if there are 2 access points, the process would be something like

```
0.00 Passenger 0 arrives
0.10 Passenger 1 arrives
0.11 Taxi 0 arrives
0.11 Passenger 0 is matching with Taxi 0
0.15 Passenger 2 arrives
0.16 Taxi 1 arrives
0.16 Passenger 1 is matching with Taxi 1
0.17 Taxi 2 arrives (and wait in the queue because 2 access points are occupied)
0.20 Passenger 0 and Taxi 0 finish and leave the system
0.20 Passenger 2 is matching with Taxi 2
```

Comment: not sure I understand the problem, can you add a more detail example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you want taxi to be consumed one at a time.  However, if a resource pool has the resources, it will fill all requests immediately.  So if three passengers request a taxi at the same time and the resource pool has three taxi, then all three request will be filled at the same time.

If you want the taxi to be consumed one at a time then you need to add a gate keeper.  In this case it would be the taxi stand, often it is sales counters.

The taxi stand is a resource pool of one resource.  The resource represents the head of the queue.  When passengers arrive they request the head of the queue, if someone else already at the head of the queue, the passenger queues and waits their turn.  Once the passenger has the head of the queue, then they request a taxi from your taxi store.  If the taxi store is empty then there will be another wait until a taxi returns.  Note that the passenger does not release the head of taxi stand queue until after their request for a taxi is actually filled.  Also note that the passenger needs to return the taxi to the taxi store after the passenger is done with the taxi

check out my example

```
"""
simulation of passengers waiting for taxis at a taxi stand

Passengers first wait to be first in line to seize the taxi stand
Then they wait for the next taxi
There is a short delay as the passenger gets into to taxi
before the passenger releases the the taxi stand, allowing 
the next passenger to wait for the next taxi

When the sim start, the taxi stand will have a queue of taxi
that will be eventualy depleted by the arriving passengers
as the passengers arrive faster then the taxi can server

programmer Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
from random import randint

class IdClass():
    """
    quick class that generates unique id's 
    for each object created
    """

    nextId = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = type(self).nextId
        type(self).nextId +=1

class Passenger(IdClass):
    """
    Passenger waiting for a taxi
    """


class Taxi(IdClass):
    """
    Taxi is the resource passengers are competing for
    """


def getTaxi(env, passenger, taxiStand, taxiQueue):
    """
    passenger waits for cab
    then takes cap for a trip
    Taxi returns after trip
    """

    

    # get in line at the taxi stand
    with taxiStand.request() as turnReq:
        print(f'{env.now} passenger {passenger.id} has entered taxi stand queue')
        yield turnReq

        # first in line, now wait for taxi
        print(f'{env.now} passenger {passenger.id} is waiting for taxi')
        taxi = yield taxiQueue.get()

        # got taxi, tine to get into cab
        print(f'{env.now} passenger {passenger.id} has taken taxi {taxi.id}')
        yield env.timeout(2)

        # now cab leaves and taxi stand is free for next passenger

    # leave stand and use taxit
    print(f'{env.now} taxi {taxi.id} has left')
    yield env.timeout(randint(10,60))

    # taxi returns for next passenger
    yield taxiQueue.put(taxi)
    print(f'{env.now} taxi {taxi.id} has return')


def genPassengers(env, taxiStand, taxiQueue):
    """
    generates arriving passengers and kicks off their taxi use
    """

    while True:
        yield env.timeout(randint(1,15))
        env.process(getTaxi(env,Passenger(), taxiStand, taxiQueue))


# create simulation
env = simpy.Environment()

# start taxiStand
taxiStand = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

# start taxi queue with 5 taxies
taxiQueue = simpy.Store(env) # unlimited capacity
taxiQueue.items = [Taxi() for _ in range(5)]

# start taxi stand with a queue of 3 passengers
for _ in range(3):
    env.process(getTaxi(env, Passenger(),taxiStand,taxiQueue))

# start generating passengers
env.process(genPassengers(env,taxiStand,taxiQueue))

# start sim
env.run(until = 100)
```

Comment: I am really sorry for this late response. What I meant by " there are queues of both taxis and passengers" is that this queue is double-sided. Both passengers and taxis arrive at the system and match with each other, then leave the system without consideration about the return of taxis. That's why I thought it was like a Store with get/put.

Comment: I think you can do a

:yield store1.get() and store2.get()

which will wait for both gets to finish before moving to the next line of code.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: looked at your original post. So when will taxi 2 and passenger 2 match?

Comment: Taxi 2 and Passenger 2 will start matching as soon as one of the pair Taxi 0-Passenger 0 or  Taxi 1-Passenger 1 finish matching and leave the taxi stand. Can you elaborate more about the idea in your previous comment? I think I haven't got it...

Comment: change taxiStand = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)  to taxiStand = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2)

Comment: if passenger 0 has arrived and taxi 0 has arrived, why does matching take any time before they leave/release the taxi stand?  I think my example is doing what you want, except I have only one matching point instead of 2, but you can change that by changing the resource compacity from 1 to 2

Comment: Sorry if my question confused you, but I don't really get what you mean by "why does matching take any time before they leave/release the taxi stand?" either. I added the next two example events in the question and hope it became more clear. I am still confused about the process of "return" taxis in your program. Is it equivalent to having independently different taxis arriving at the system after some time (like passengers), rather than having 5 taxis keeping leaving and coming back?

Comment: at time 0.11 a match happens, but the pair does not leave till 0.20.  so there is a delay of 0.9.  If you change the taxiStand capacity from 1 to 2, my code will do what you want.  also look at the simpy doc examples for resources and stores.  realPython.com also has a section on simpy

Comment: As for the taxi return.  Yes, you could drop the yield taxiQueue.put(taxi) and have a different process generate replacement taxis for the taxiQueue.  Doing it my way with a fix number of taxis would allow each taxi to collect usage statistics

Comment: Thank you for your patience!! I think I got your idea :-)